# Colors in physics

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

We know colors are related to EM waves. In colors theory is used HSB to define colors: Hue, Saturation and Brightness. I'd like to know how Hue, Saturation  and Brightness are related to physics aspect of EM waves (such as frequenty and intensity for example). So what is the exact definition of Hue, Saturation and Brightness in physics.

Comment: I do not believe an EM wave has any of those things as they all refer to a mix, except maybe brightness which would typically go by a more accurate name.

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425649/313612. A bit complicated!

Comment: TLDR: There are no colors in physics. Colors are all in your head. In physics, we can only talk about the [_spectral density_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) of a light source.

Comment: There are no colors in physics. Colors are all in your head. [What is Gray, from a physics POV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364)