# What is the frequency of white light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, frequency

We can see white LED light after a combination of red, green & blue LED together. Then what is the frequency of white light? Whether it lies between 380 Hz - 700 Hz?

There has to be a frequency as every physical object carry its vibrational frequency. Or we have to conclude by saying that there is no existing physical colour called white. It is energy, not a colour. That means we see a direct form of energy through our eye.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is white a single color?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228926/)

Comment: this article will help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Physiology_of_color_perception  this answer of mine to a similar question has useful links https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421217/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a specific frequency -- it has a frequency distribution.

You don't even need to go as far as white light -- just consider a "camel hump" wave, like $\sin ax+\sin bx$ -- what's the frequency of a light wave that looks like this? The answer is that its frequency isn't a fixed value, but a distribution, taking values $a/2\pi$ and $b/2\pi$ with half probability each. In general, if you have some function $f(x)$, the way to obtain this **frequency distribution** is to decompose $f(x)$ in terms of sinusoids -- this is precisely the **Fourier transform**.

In the specific case you mentioned, position and momentum ("frequency") are "Fourier duals" of each other. If you have a sinusoid (by which I mean $e^{2\pi i\xi x}$), you have complete uncertainty about the position, but have a precise value for the momentum: $h\xi$. On the other hand, if you had localised your position completely (to a Dirac delta function), you would find a sinusoid in momentum-space.

These distributions are called the "wavefunctions" in position and momentum basis respectively, and this duality is the "uncertainty principle" -- read more about this in my [quantum mechanics articles here](https://thewindingnumber.blogspot.com/p/2103.html) (specifically article 4). In the specific case of white light, white light isn't really a well-defined concept in physics -- it has to do with human eyesight and what visible light entails, but nonetheless the frequency of white light is indeed a distribution with non-zero variance.